# "Ignored" from what exactly is Debbie referring to?

Tags: plot-explanation, oceans-8

In *Ocean's Eight (2018)*, two con artists Debbie and Lou looking to rob a necklace at museum.
They looking some profiles for the job, so Lou asks Debbie's opinion
on a profile:

> Debbie Ocean: I barely know the guy.
>
> Lou: What's wrong with a him?
>
> Debbie Ocean: A him gets noticed, a her gets **ignored**, and for once, we
> wanna be **ignored**.

"Ignored" from what exactly is Debbie referring to?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are looking for people to join the heist that will be ignored, not drawing the attention of security. They're saying that people who appear to be men will be noticed; people who appear to be women will be ignored, and that's their goal in this project: to be ignored.

See https://www.insider.com/oceans-8-empowering-times-up-2018-6